# iOS : Apps must follow the iOS Data Storage?

Tags: iphone, ios

My iOS app was rejected because I use the `/Document` directory to store downloaded images.

I will move the downloaded images in the `/Library/Caches` directory to solve my problem.

But my sqLite database also contains elements manually created by the user.
This file must be copied into the `/Library/Caches` directory or `/Documents` directory to be accepted by the Reviewer ?

Sincerely,
Maxime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the iOS Storage Guidelines (which can be found at http://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/) you should put all user-generated content in the Documents directory and all re-downloadable content in the Caches directory. So you should be fine putting the sqLite database there.

The background on this is that starting with iOS 5 the Documents directory is backed up to iCloud. As a lot of apps tend to store their complete data there the iCloud backups get rather large, which uses up the free space and creates network traffic, both of which in turn anger the user because he/she wonders why. To mitigate this Apple now seems to take a much closer look on what is saved into the Documents directory and if this is possibly regeneratable content (e.g. downloadable files).

Beware, that the Caches directory can and will be purged on iOS 5 by the operating system at times when the free space on the device gets low. Thus your app cannot longer just assume that everything is there as it was before but you rather have to re-check every time you access something out of your cache.

Comment: So I will put my database in the /Document directory and re-downloading images files in the /Library/caches if it's necesary. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

The data manually created can be stored with in your app directory.

You can use below code to get the current directory -

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

and then append you file name to get the full path.

```
NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.format"] ;
```